# Laravel Выбор таблицы при авторизации

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

При авторизации нужно обратится именно в ту таблицу которая была выбрана при входе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**User.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username','avatar', 'password', 'steam_id', 
    ];
    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
      $isRememberTokenAttribute = $key == $this->getRememberTokenName();
      if (!$isRememberTokenAttribute)
      {
        parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
      }
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
    protected $table = 'server_1_users';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**LoginController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    public function showLoginForm()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function username()
    {
        return 'steam_id';
    }
}
```

Как могу указать при проверке данных именно на таблицу которая была выбрана при авторизации

```
protected $table = 'server_1_users';

protected $table = 'server_2_users';
...
```

Comment: Подпишись на событие создания модели `User` в своем контроллере, при наступления события ты получишь модель пользователя, в модели же меняешь название таблицы.

Comment: Мне кажется хранить разные названия таблиц для разных серверов не очень красиво. Попробуй почитать про подключения. Посмотри файл `config/database.php` - там можно добавить различные подключения.